# Meaning of extending a smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the meaning of the statement "extending a smooth function"?
If suppose $f(t)$ is a smooth function in the interval $(0,\pi)$, what does it mean when we say extend $f$ smoothly to $[0,\pi]$?
Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $g$ is smooth on $[0,\pi]$ if there exists a smooth function $h$ that coincides with $g$ on $[0,\pi]$ but is defined on a larger *open* interval.

Extending $f$ to $[0,\pi]$ means finding such a function $g$ that coincides with $f$ on $(0,\pi)$.

It may not be possible to do this. For example, $1/x$ is smooth on $(0,\pi)$ but cannot be extended smoothly.